# How can I calculate a measure of 'rotational mobility' from Euler angles?

Tags: python, math, virtual-reality, euler-angles

Odd question, but I'm having trouble boiling it down to a coherent question.

I have sampled data (60Hz) from Brekel OpenVR recorder, which includes the following parameters for the HMD itself:

- X, Y, Z positional coordinates
- Euler angles rotX, rotY, rot.

I'm processing the data in python. Overall, what I'm trying to do is to **calculate measures of mobility**: did someone look around more or less during a segment, and did they move around more or less?

For the positional coordinates that wasn't too difficult, I was able to calculate displacement, velocity, etc., by using the distances between subsequent positions. Now for the Euler angles, I'm having more trouble.

I've searched for the answer to my question, but none of the answer seemed to 'click'. **What I think I need, is to convert the Euler angles to a directional vector, and then calculate the angle between the directional vectors of subsequent samples to see how much the gaze direction shifted.** Once I have those, I can calculate means and SDs per subject, to see which of them looked around more (that's the idea anyway). I am unclear on the mathematics though. It would have been easier if my coordinates were roll, pitch, yaw, but I'm struggling with the Euler angles.

Suppose the Euler angles for two subsequent samples are:

- (rotX, rotY, rot) = (20°, 25°, 50°)
- (rotX2, rotY2, rot2) = (30°, 35°, 60°)

**How can I quantify with what angle the direction of the HMD changed between those two samples?**

Comment: Be reassured, Euler angles are not more difficult than roll/pitch/yaw: they are *as* difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to convert Euler angles to unit vectors, and another to take the angle between two unit vectors

```
from math import cos, sin, atan2, degrees, radians, sqrt
from numpy import dot, cross

def to_unit_vector(pitch, yaw, roll):
    # Convert degrees to radians
    pitch = radians(pitch)
    yaw = radians(yaw)
    roll = radians(roll)
    # Calculate unit vector components
    x = cos(yaw) * cos(pitch)
    y = sin(yaw) * cos(pitch)
    z = sin(pitch)
    return x, y, z

def angle_between(a, b):
    # returns angle in degrees
    return degrees(atan2(sqrt(dot(cross(a, b), cross(a, b))), dot(a, b)))
```

Then for example

```
>>> u = to_unit_vector(20, 25, 50)
>>> u
(0.8516507396391465, 0.39713126196710286, 0.3420201433256687)
>>> v = to_unit_vector(30, 35, 60)
>>> v
(0.7094064799162225, 0.49673176489215404, 0.49999999999999994)
>>> angle_between(u, v)
13.481723224800309
```

Comment: This is only a part of the answer, as general solid rotation has 3 DOFs.

Comment: Cool! Just a question: I was under the impression that Euler angles were not the same as roll, pitch, yaw coordinates. Does this not affect the solution?

Comment: Roll, pitch, and yaw are domain specific nicknames for Euler angles. For example sometimes they are called heading, elevation, and bank. There are other names for them too.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'm accepting your answer. Just a final stupid question: where does the formula in the second function come from? I would've used this: http://www.analyzemath.com/stepbystep_mathworksheets/3D_vectors/angle_vectors.png?ezimgfmt=rs:338x165/rscb1/ngcb1/notWebP

Comment: @Inkidu616 That equation should be equivalent, it should compute the same answer

Comment: Alright, thanks. I had a final thought, as I was getting ready to implement this solution. Which of the rotations do I map on the pitch and yaw variables (since only those are used)? I would assume pitch is the Y rotation (since height seems to be the Y-axis in Unity). From what I found, it doesn't seem to matter (since we're losing one df) but I'm not sure.